# Importing variables from python into a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to be able to transfer a variable set in python to be used in a batch file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set environment variable in your python script, and use that variable in your batch file

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['x'] = 'a'
>>> os.system('echo %x%')
# prints 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use os.putenv after import of os module. Also, take a look on [PyBat](http://pybat.sourceforge.net/).